# Deviance Residuals in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

How are the deviance residuals (highlighted in yellow) calculated in logistic regression? Please help me to get a good understanding by using a clear example!

Image source: Google

[image]

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166585/pearson-vs-deviance-residuals-in-logistic-regression

Comment: Thankyou, I am looking for a very simple toy logistic regression example, where I could see and understand the calculation step by step. Hope you understand my need !

Comment: I have updated the answer linked to above with a coding example, so see [this post again](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166585/pearson-vs-deviance-residuals-in-logistic-regression/455665#455665). I am therefore voting to close your question as a duplicate, but feel free to ask follow up questions.

Comment: yes, thankyou! this is what i was looking for ...amazing :)